# Обработка нажатия только определенных ссылок в QWebView

Tags: c++, qt5

Использую следующий механизм для обработки нажатия ссылок в браузере:

```
browser->page()->setLinkDelegationPolicy(QWebPage::LinkDelegationPolicy::DelegateAllLinks);
QObject::connect(browser, &QWebView::linkClicked, this, [urlHandler](const QUrl& url) {
    urlHandler(url);
});
```

Таким образом, обрабатываются все ссылки на странице. Но мне необходимо перехватывать только определенные ссылки, для остальных же - определен JS-скрипт, который и должен выполняться.

Есть ли возможность сделать такое поведение стандартными средствами или необходимо изменять исходники Qt?

Используемая версия Qt - 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартных средств реализации не нашел, поэтому пошел обходным путем.

Нужные ссылки для обработки оформлять специальным образом: например, добавлять префикс перед основным url-адресом. При получении сигнала проверять наличие префикса. Если необходимо продолжить загрузку, то можно использовать функцию [load](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#load) (пример):

```
QObject::connect(browser, &QWebView::linkClicked, this, [=](const QUrl& url) {
    if (hasPrefix(url)) {
       urlHandler(url);
    } else {
       browser->load(url);
    }
});
```

Также есть сигнал [linkHovered](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#linkHovered) в классе QWebPage, с помощью которого можно получить заголовок, адрес и текст ссылки.